# Optimization Word Problem, revenue

Tags: calculus, optimization

A sorority plans a bus trip to the Great Mall of America during Thanksgiving break. The bus they charter seats $44$ and charge a flat rate of $350\$$ plus $35\$$ per person. However, for every empty seat, the charge per person is increased by $2\$$. There is a minimum of $10$ passengers. The sorority itself will pay the flat rate and the additional amount above $35\$$ per person.

a) Construct a model for the revenue made by the bus company as a function of the number of passengers.

b) Construct a model for the amount the sorority pays as a function of the number of passengers.

c) For what number of passengers will the bus company's revenue be greatest? What will the bus company's greatest revenues be?

d) For what number of passengers will the amount the sorority pays be least? What will the least amount the sorority pays be?

Comment: Hi.  What have you tried?  You have tried or seen some optimization problems, so can you use that information to get somewhere?

Comment: for A I thought maybe the equation is 350+35x+2(44-x) and then for B I thought maybe it was 350+2(44-x). @ChristopherErnst

Comment: No.  You are adding 2(44- x) but that is the increase in the cost for each side but that is per person.  You need to multiply by x.  For A, it is 350+ 35x+ 2(44- x)x= 350+ 123x- 2x^2 and for B 350+ 2(44- x)x= 350+ 88x- 2x^2.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track for A).

Think about it.  You have the first part... clearly the cost per seat is $\$35$ and the additional flat rate of $ \$350 $ is tacked on regardless.  However, your intuition about your second part is wrong.

If everyone shows up, then the revenue is just $350 + 35x$  but if 1 person fails to come, the ticket prices increases by $ \$2$ per person.  If 2 fail to show, the ticket price increases by $ \$4 $ per person.  We can look at it like this;

$$n=44;  R(44)=350+35(44)=350+(35+2(0))44$$
$$n=43;  R(43)=350+37(43)=350+(35+2(1))43$$
$$n=42;  R(42)=350+39(42)=350+(35+2(2))42$$
$$n=m;  R(m)=350+(35+2(44-m))m$$
$$=350+(35+88-2m)m=350+123m-2m^2$$
Therefore the bus company revenue function is $R(n)=350+123m-2m^2$.

With that in mind, try part b now...think about what part from $R(n)$ you don't need given the restriction for the sorority payment.

Comment: So for part B would it be 350 + 2(44-m) since the sorority doesn't have to pay the 35 dollars per passenger?

Comment: Or would it be 350 + 88m - 2m^2 ?

Comment: The one I upvoted...

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense with part D, the number of passengers that they would pay the least would be 44 passengers, but thats not what I get with the derivative of that equation

Comment: Your squared term is negative so you have a maximum using the derivative (I assume you are looking for f'(x)=0).  You need the minimum ...

Comment: The least the sorority will pay is $350...no matter how many passengers under 44 travel, the sorority is only paying for the flat rate then, according to your payment scheme above, right?

Comment: Right, but that is not shown on the graph which is where my confusion is coming from.

Comment: Is there a picture for the problem?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well usually in order to find the max or min you graph to derivative of the function, and although I already know when the sorority will pay the lowest, it makes me think that the equation is wrong when I can't see the right answer on the derivative graph.

Comment: The right answer is on the derivative graph.  The derivative is 88-4x and the minimum comes at the upper bound of your domain, 44.  At that point, f'(44)=-88, which is the lowest bound in your range.  When there are 44 passengers, you are only paying the flat rate.

Answer (score 0):

A) $350 + ((44-x)2+35)x$
B) $350 + ((44-x)2x$
C) $\frac {d}{dx} (350 + ((44-x)2+35)x) = 0$  (adjusted to the nearest whole passenger)
D) The bus is full -- $\$350$